# jupyter notebook keeps crashing

Tags: python, jupyter

I start up Jupyter Notebook from the cmd and it works with no issues. But when I open the localhost, no folders are shown and it just says `Server error: error`. When I refresh, the folders show up, but immediately after Firefox tells me the script is unresponsive. After a few seconds, the entire browser crashes. What is happening, and is there any way I can fix this?